# Custom post type and comments in wordpress

Tags: forms, wordpress, post, comments

Is it possible in wordpress to display comments and comment form on custom post type, and how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comments not showing in custom post type - Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604206/comments-not-showing-in-custom-post-type-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

It is very important that you put this attributes "comments" in this line :

```
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'author', 'page-attributes' ),
```

in your functions.php file

```
// register post type MySpecialPost
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_MySpecialPost' );
function register_cpt_MySpecialPost() {
    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'MySpecialPost', 'MySpecialPost' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'MySpecialPost', 'MySpecialPost' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Ajouter', 'MySpecialPost' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Ajouter une MySpecialPost', 'MySpecialPost' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Modifier', 'MySpecialPost' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'Nouvelle MySpecialPost', 'MySpecialPost' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Voir la MySpecialPost', 'MySpecialPost' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Recherche', 'MySpecialPost' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'Aucune MySpecialPost trouvé', 'MySpecialPost' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Aucune MySpecialPost trouv&eacute;', 'MySpecialPost' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Service:', 'MySpecialPost' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'MySpecialPost', 'MySpecialPost' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'author', 'page-attributes' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 21,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page'
    );
    register_post_type( 'MySpecialPost', $args );
}
```